# Bibliography or Content page heading (problem with \chapter*{})

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I'm using `\documentclass{book}` and I have also redefined my `\chapter` and `\part` heading styles. However, these styles do not apply to the heading of the Content page (the word "Contents") or the bibliography page (the word "Bibliography"). How do I modify their styles? I mean the way the word Contents or Bibliography is displayed on top of the corresponding pages. The same hold for any section that uses \chapter{}* as the heading style. Any ideas? Here is an MWE. Please take a look at the heading of the contents the word "contents" or "Acknowledgements". I want them to have the same style as the chapter heading minus the number!

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{type1cm}

\setlength\epigraphwidth{.6\textwidth}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\rmfamily}
{\sffamily\flushright\fontsize{100}{0}\textbf{\textcolor{black!25}{\thechapter\vskip-10pt}}}{-10pt}
{\flushright\fontsize{25}{0}{#1}\vskip60pt}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
 {0pt}{-40pt}{0pt}


\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\rmfamily}
  {\sffamily\flushright\fontsize{100}{0}\textbf{\textcolor{black!25}{\thepart\vskip-10pt}}}{-10pt}
  {\flushright\fontsize{25}{0}{#1}\vskip60pt}
\titlespacing*{\part}
  {0pt}{-40pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
Let's acknowledge those who answer this question! 

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\epigraphhead[450]{Fairy tales are more than true: not because they tell us that dragons exist, but because they tell us dragons can be beaten.\par\hfill\textsc{C.K. Chesterton}}
\part{A Test Part Title}


\chapter{A Test Chapter Title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `tableofcontents` uses a `chapter*` command, which does not set the headings correctly, as well as `bibliography`. You have to define styles of your own and explicitly set the `\markboth` commands to `\contentsname` and `\bibname`, for example

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: exactly! This my problem with any other section for which I use `\chapter*{}` too. It simply does not work well. Here is how I define my chapter style. There is not `\markboth` to modify => `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\rmfamily}
  {\sffamily\flushright\fontsize{100}{0}\textbf{\textcolor{black!25}{\thechapter\vskip-10pt}}}{-10pt}
  {\flushright\fontsize{25}{0}{#1}\vskip60pt}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{-40pt}{0pt}`

Comment: You did not say, that you use `titlesec` in your post. A MWE would help

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Following your comment I added an MWE. Could you please help me how to redefine the styles for contents (and acknowledgements, etc)?

Comment: I will take a look as soon as possible

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Thanks a lot! This looks like to be a formidable problem, I could't find a way to solve it for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `numberless` feature of `titlesec`. You don't need `explicit`. Moreover, using `\flushright` is wrong, as it adds vertical spacings. Also some other things have been streamlined.

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % just for the example
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{type1cm}

\setlength\epigraphwidth{.6\textwidth}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\rmfamily}
  {\fontsize{100}{0}\sffamily\bfseries\raggedleft
   \textcolor{black!25}{\thechapter}}
  {0pt}
  {\raggedleft\fontsize{25}{32}\normalfont}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\rmfamily}
  {\fontsize{100}{0}\sffamily\bfseries\raggedleft\vphantom{1}}
  {0pt}
  {\raggedleft\fontsize{25}{32}\normalfont}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-40pt}{60pt}


\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\rmfamily}
  {\fontsize{100}{0}\sffamily\bfseries\raggedleft
   \textcolor{black!25}{\thepart}}
  {0pt}
  {\raggedleft\fontsize{25}{32}\normalfont}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{-40pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
Let's acknowledge those who answer this question! 

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\epigraphhead[450]{Fairy tales are more than true: not because they tell us that dragons 
exist, but because they tell us dragons can be beaten.\par\hfill\textsc{C.K. Chesterton}}

\part{A Test Part Title}


\chapter{A Test Chapter Title}

Text
\end{document}
```

### Output of `\chapter*`

[image]

### Output of `\chapter`

[image]

Comment: what are these lines all over the document? A lot of horizontal and vertical lines appear. I guess because of Geome

Comment: @LatexQuest Those are the effect of `\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}`, which I used just for showing the placement of the number/title with respect to the page. Remove it in a production version.

Comment: I noticed it, exactly. Just a question, why the `\scshape` is not applied to titles? I guess `\sffamily` should do that right? Now in Chpater I have \scshape but in ack. I don't, for instance!

Comment: @LatexQuest I can see `\scshape` nowhere. You have to know that there is no small caps with Computer Modern Sans Serif.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very nice. Just a question, how can I put the titles to appear in `\scshape` based on your current style?

Comment: I noticed I cannot force it in the middle of `\sffamily\bfseries\raggedleft`.

Comment: I could figure out how to make them `\scshape` in the heading. I also want to make sure they look `\scshape` in the TOC. How can I do that? Specially for bibliography for instance that I can not use \chaptet[TOC](Title).

Comment: @LatexQuest The appearance of titles in the TOC is better managed with the `tocloft` package.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to access it on your code?

Comment: @LatexQuest It's a completely different problem; `tocloft` is a specific package for acting on the formatting of the table of contents and similar lists.

Comment: So, you suggest I ask it as a different question?

Comment: @LatexQuest The usage of `tocloft` is not too difficult; try its manual, if you're still stuck, then ask a new question.