# Defining a header style for acknowledgements (saying no to Chapter*{} !!!)

Tags: chapters, titlesec

I'm using \documentclass{book} and I have also redefined my \chapter and \part heading styles. However, these styles do not apply to the heading of the Acknowledgements page (the word "Acknowledgements ") or other similar pages. Is there a way to redefine a style so that I can avoid using `\chapter*{}`. Here is an MWE. Please take a look at the heading of the acknowledgement. I want them to have the same style as the chapter heading excluding the number!

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{type1cm}

\setlength\epigraphwidth{.6\textwidth}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\rmfamily}
{\sffamily\flushright\fontsize{100}{0}\textbf{\textcolor{black!25}{\thechapter\vskip-10pt}}}{-10pt}
{\flushright\fontsize{25}{0}{#1}\vskip60pt}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
 {0pt}{-40pt}{0pt}


\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\rmfamily}
  {\sffamily\flushright\fontsize{100}{0}\textbf{\textcolor{black!25}{\thepart\vskip-10pt}}}{-10pt}
  {\flushright\fontsize{25}{0}{#1}\vskip60pt}
\titlespacing*{\part}
  {0pt}{-40pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
Let's acknowledge those who answer this question! 

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{A Test Chapter Title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In as much is this different to your other question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193814/bibliography-or-content-page-heading-problem-with-chapter? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: A bit different right? For Contents and Bibliography you do not have access to heading style directly. As you said, it is automatically set to chapter*. For Ack. for instance I use directly chapter* so there might be a way to redefine or define a style for it. Anyway, nobody could solve either problems. For the the other one, I'm waiting for your help for about 5 days ;-) So, please help me if you can :-)

Comment: I wrote yesterday or two days before, that I will have a look, but not 5 days ago ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer:Right, I guess your first comments go back to 5 days ago then :-) Anyway, following your suggestion I prepared an MWE. I hope you can help me with it ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: BTW, If you think you can answer both question in one answer, I'll be happy to remove this question, indeed.

Comment: Bernard was quicker than me ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `numberless` key from titlesec to format `\chapter*`. I improved and simplified a little your code, using titlesec's tools. I added the geometry package with option `showframe` to visualize more precisely the resulting layout.

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
%\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[nomarginpar, showframe]{geometry}

\setlength\epigraphwidth{.6\textwidth}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filleft}
{\sffamily\fontsize{100}{0}\selectfont\bfseries\color{black!25}\thechapter}{10pt}
{\Huge#1}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
 {0pt}{-8.6pt}{60pt}

\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[display]
{\filleft}
{}{68.5pt}
{\Huge#1\vskip60pt}
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter, numberless}
 {0pt}{-8.6pt}{-30pt}


\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\filleft}
{\sffamily\fontsize{100}{0}\selectfont\bfseries\color{black!25}\thechapter}{10pt}
{\Huge#1}
\titlespacing*{\part}
 {0pt}{-8.6pt}{60pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
Let's acknowledge those who answer this question!

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{A Test Chapter Title}

Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]